# Safe way to install infotainment box

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz, safety, backup-camera, wire

I am installing a video interface box into my Mercedes, this enables me to add support for a reversing camera feed.

I have positioned the video interface box behind the infotainment screen like so:

[image]

For safety, should I wrap the whole thing in tesa tape? I will certainly wrap all connections in tesa tape, but do I need to wrap the whole unit in tesa tape? The unit is made out of metal.

Thanks for your time, Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is, no, you don't need to wrap the entire thing in Tesa tape. As long as the box is secured (won't rattle around), you shouldn't have an issue with it. The real reason you'd want to do that is so it doesn't annoy you making noise behind the dash. Really, there's no safety concern there. You can most likely secure it with some zip ties if an interference fit isn't good enough.

As far as the connections go, I'd recommend you *not* covering them with the tape for the simple reason if you ever need to take it apart, they are going to be a PITB. I would, however, recommend you doing the wiring and any joints you've soldered or connected wires together. This will keep them from having issues in the future.